# iUI Framework vs. Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, iui

I am building an app that will take most of its content from Facebook i.e. photos, personal info, etc.

I was wondering if anyone can give me advice on which framework would be the most suitable, iUI or Cocoa Touch? What sort of apps would be suitable for the iUI framework and what apps are more suitable using the standard Cocoa Touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native apps run quickly, can be used offline and can make use of more of the device's hardware.

Web apps are more portable (you could make them available on Android as well, for example) and don't have to be vetted for inclusion in the app store.